# SMS messages not being sent using Twilio and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sms, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to integrate Twilio and my rails application to send different text messages based on what option is chosen and saved to the database in the form. However after studying the docs and viewing the example applications they provide (Send ETA Notifications), saving the completed form, no text message is sent and I cannot figure out why. I would love some suggestions

job_status are the options to choose from which the text message body needs to change with:

```
 JOB_STATUSES = ["Wildey Que", "In Service-Bay", "Awaiting Approval", 
 "Awaiting Parts", "Jackson Collection Que", "Wildey Collection Que", 
 "Completed"]
```

message_sender.rb

```
class MessageSender

    require 'twilio-ruby'

  def self.send_message(job_id, host, to, message)
    new.send_message(job_id, host, to, message)
  end

  def initialize
    # To find TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID, TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN visit
    # https://www.twilio.com/console
    account_sid = ENV['---'] (These are entered)
    auth_token  = ENV['---']
    @client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)
  end


  def send_message(job_id, host, to, message)
    @client.messages.create(
      from:  twilio_number,
      to:    to,
      body:  message,
      status_callback: "http://#{host}/jobs/#{job_id}"
    )
  end

  private

  def twilio_number
    # A Twilio number you control - choose one from:
    # https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming
    # Specify in E.164 format, e.g. "+16519998877"
    ENV['+17652957305']
  end
end
```

jobs_controller.rb

```
 class JobsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :authenticate_user!



      # GET /jobs
      # GET /jobs.json
      def index
        if(params.has_key? (:job_status))
          @jobs = Job.where(job_status: params[:job_status]).order("created_at desc")
        else
          @jobs = Job.all.order("created_at desc")
        end
      end

      # GET /jobs/1
      # GET /jobs/1.json
      def show
      end

      # GET /jobs/new
      def new
        @job = current_user.jobs.build
      end

      # GET /jobs/1/edit
      def edit
      end

      #TWILLIO INITILIZATION 

     def send_initial_notification
        @job.job_status = :Wildey_Que
        if @job.save
          message = 'Equip4you: Thanks for dropping your machine off, we will keep you updated here every step of the way'
          notify(message)
        else
          redirect_with_error
        end
      end

      def send_delivery_notification
        @job.job_status = :Completed
        if @job.save
          message = 'Equip4you: Thank you for allowing us to take care of your machine for you, if you have any further questions or concerns feel free to contact 425-9999'
          notify(message)
        else
          redirect_with_error
        end
      end

      #END TWILLIO INIT

      # POST /jobs
      # POST /jobs.json
      def create
        @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)

        respond_to do |format|
          if @job.save
            format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @job }
          else
            format.html { render :new }
            format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1
      # PATCH/PUT /jobs/1.json
      def update
        respond_to do |format|
          if @job.update(job_params)
            format.html { redirect_to @job, notice: 'Job was successfully updated.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @job }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @job.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end

      # DELETE /jobs/1
      # DELETE /jobs/1.json
      def destroy
        @job.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to jobs_url, notice: 'Job was successfully destroyed.' }
          format.json { head :no_content }
        end
      end

      private

      # TWILLIO INNIT

      def notify(message)
        MessageSender.send_message(
          @job.id, request.host, @job.cell_number, message)
        redirect_to jobs_url, notice: 'Message was delivered'
      end

      def redirect_with_error
        message = "An error has occurred updating the ticket status"
        redirect_to orders_url, flash: { error: message }
      end

      #TWILLIO INIT END


        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
        def set_job
          @job = Job.find(params[:id])
        end

        # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
        def job_params
          params.require(:job).permit(:job_status, :purchase_name, :contact_name, :cell_number, :home_number, :other_number, :other_number, :address, :machine_mod, :item_number, :serial_number, :concern, :accessories, :pickup_location, :paid, :invoice_number, :outcome, :avatar)
        end
    end

Routes.rb

require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :jobs
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'jobs#index'


  post '/jobs/new', to: 'jobs#new', as: 'initial_notifications'
  post '/jobs/new', to: 'jobs#new', as: 'delivery_notifications'
```

routes.rb

```
require 'sidekiq/web'

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :jobs
  devise_for :users
  root to: 'jobs#index'


  post '/jobs/new', to: 'jobs#new', as: 'initial_notifications'
  post '/jobs/new', to: 'jobs#new', as: 'delivery_notifications'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this def. It looks weird.

```
  def twilio_number
    # A Twilio number you control - choose one from:
    # https://www.twilio.com/console/phone-numbers/incoming
    # Specify in E.164 format, e.g. "+16519998877"
    ENV['+17652957305']
  end
```